# NET5 WebAPI docker container successfully deploy in azure container instance but cant access via url

Tags: c#, azure, docker, asp.net-core, .net-5

I have a image in docker hub which can running perfectly with docker-compose and separately. But when I deploy it into azure container instance it deployed but can't access via provided url which is `helloams.centralindia.azurecontainer.io` this. But till now I didn't find out any issue with it, everything seems fine.

Here , How I EXPOSE my container port

```
EXPOSE 5000
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
    
ENTRYPOINT ["./AMS", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

Here is my azure container logs ,

[Azure Container Log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMEeQ.png)

Here I forward the port `5000`

[Azure Container Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zczBR.png)

What can I do now ?

Comment: I tried it with 'swagger/index.html' but didn't get any.

Comment: And what if you include port 5000 in your url? Port forwarding isn't the same as rerouting the port from 80/443 to 5000.

Comment: got this message "This helloams.centralindia.azurecontainer.io page can’t be found" & I didn't mention 80/443 port in my docker file. @gunr2171

Comment: Change the url to "http://helloams.centralindia.azurecontainer.io:5000/swagger". You need to include the port 5000 in your url, as I said.

Comment: yeah, it works. But how can I avoid to use manual port forwarding , like I dont want to use "....io:5000/swagger" but "....io/swagger" ? @gunr2171

Comment: It looks like Azure Container Instances doesn't support port mapping. Either change the port you are listening to in the Dockerfile or use a reverse proxy.

Comment: got it, lets have a try with default port 80, I saw azure suggest it during container instance creation. thanks  you so much for your help. @gunr2171